# asyncio: loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_task(f)) prints "Task exception was never retrieved" even though it clearly was propagated

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, coroutine, python-asyncio

For some reason this program prints the following warning:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<coro() done, defined at /usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/coroutines.py:139> exception=SystemExit(2,)>
```

even though the exception is clearly retrieved and propagated, as `caught SystemExit!` is printed to the terminal, and process status code becomes 2.

The same thing happens with Python 2 and trollius.

Am I missing something?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def comain():
    raise SystemExit(2)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(comain())
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except SystemExit:
        print("caught SystemExit!")
        raise
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: is there any reason not to use `loop.run_until_complete(comain())` which works as expected?

Comment: I need a task object because I call `task.cancel()` in a `KeyboardInterrupt` handler (not shown in this snippet).

Comment: you could add `if not task.cancelled(): task.result()` into the finally block. Though I don't know whether it is the intended behavior that you have to call `task.result()` or `task.exception()` manually (I would expect `run_until_complete()` do it for you).

Answer (score 7):

`SystemExit` seems to be a special case. If, for example, you raise and catch an `Exception`, you won't see any errors.
The way around this seems to be to manually retrieve the exception using `Task.exception()`:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def comain():
    raise SystemExit(2)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(comain())
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except SystemExit:
        print("caught SystemExit!")
        task.exception()
        raise
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**EDIT**

Actually, all `BaseException` subclasses will behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` are different cases. Normal `Exception` won't cause the same issue for example.

You can chain the `comain` coroutine inside another to consume the exception like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def comain():
    raise SystemExit(2)

@asyncio.coroutine
def another():
    try:
        yield from comain()
    except SystemExit:
        print ("consumed")

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(another())
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except SystemExit:
        print("caught SystemExit!")
        raise
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here - I am calling `another()` instead of `comain()` and inside `another()` I am handling the exception from `comain()`.

Comment: My intention is to let this exception escape to the top level, so the interpreter will be terminated.